# Explicitar local do template no Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, mtv

Estou utilizando Django para um projeto, mas me deparei com uma duvida.

No meu arquivo `settings.py` tenho a seguinte configuração de *templates*:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'tests/templates'),
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'core/templates')
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

E o seguinte método no meu arquivo `view.py`

> O Django utiliza o modelo MTV, então a "view" é equivalente a o
>   controller no modelo MVC

```
def index(request):
    template = loader.get_template('create.html')
    return HttpResponse(template.render())
```

Eu tenho dois diretórios o "tests/templates" e o "core/templates", quando utilizo o método `get_template` ele pega de qualquer um dos diretórios.

Se crio um arquivo chamado "create.html" nos dois diretórios ele pega o que esta dentro da minha "aplicação" onde se encontra o arquivo "view.py", se removo o arquivo "create.html" de "tests", automaticamente ele pega o que esta na pasta "core".

> Django separa o código em "aplicações", que funciona como uma especie
>   de modulo.

Eu gostaria de definir de qual pasta (aplicação) vem o meu template.

**UPDATE**

Encontrei na [documentação](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial03/) uma forma, mas achei redundante, colocar o mesmo nome da aplicação dentro da pasta template, se já existe a separação da aplicação, porque criaria outra separação dentro de template? Existe alguma forma de utilizar o próprio nome da aplicação para isso?

Answer (score 1):

De acordo com a documentação do Django:

```
get_template(template_name , using = None)
```

Essa função carrega o modelo com o nome fornecido e retorna um objeto Template. O tipo exato do valor de retorno depende do backend que carregou o modelo. Cada backend tem sua própria classe Template .
`get_template()` tenta cada mecanismo de modelo em ordem até que um seja bem-sucedido. Se o modelo não puder ser encontrado, ele gera `TemplateDoesNotExist` . Se o modelo for encontrado, mas contiver uma sintaxe inválida, ele aumentará o `TemplateSyntaxError`.
A maneira como os modelos são pesquisados ​​e carregados depende do backend e da configuração de cada mecanismo.
Se você quiser restringir a pesquisa a um mecanismo de modelo específico, passe o `NAME` do mecanismo no argumento `using`.

Comment: Mas como configuro o backend?

Comment: Poderia mostrar sua `view` ?

Comment: Na minha view esta assim return render(request, 'tests/create.html', {'form': form}), mas eu tive que criar dentro da pasta template uma pasta chamada tests.

Comment: Acredito que basta você em `TEMPLATES` trocar as posições no seu `DIRS` assim: `'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'core/templates'),                                                  
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'tests/templates'),                                                                  ]` se der certo me avisa.

Comment: Então, esta funcionando, o problema não é deixar funcionando, isso eu já consegui, como coloquei na pergunta eu vi como funciona na documentação, o problema é que queria pegar automaticamente o nome da aplicação para não precisar criar pastas dentro de template.

Comment: Você queria poder especificar de qual aplicativo o template pertence ?

Comment: Isso, eu consigo fazer isso criando uma pasta dentro da pasta template, mas acho isso desnecessário, já que já tenho o nome da aplicação para diferenciar isso.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81428/discussion-between-thiagoluizs-and-wictor-chaves).